# Is there a way which i can use to pass a hidden input element value as a form action parameter when updating as part of update route in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have managed to pass an id to a form as a hidden input element and would like to use the same id as a parameter when sending a PATCH request to update a single row in database.

```
    <div class="container">
        <!-- update route which requires id of the row u are trying to update and the link-->
        <form action="{{route('transactions.update',  )}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <p>Fullnames</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <h6 id="names"></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <p>Account</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <h6 id="account"></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <p>Meter</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <h6 id="meter"></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- id passed from a selected value in table-->
            <input type="hidden" id="trans_id">
            <div class="row justify-content-around">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm m-2 w-75" style="background-color: #335b7d; color: white">Approve</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-around">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger  w-75">Reject</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Never trust client input. Even though the input is hidden in the browser window, it is visible and editable in the code. If you trust this input to update what seems to be transactions, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The site or may i say is only available to administrators so no one will have access to it besides the admins